# SQL Server write .pdf from inserted table (filestream) using trigger getting empty files

Tags: sql-server, triggers, filestream

I'm trying to create a **TRIGGER AFTER INSERT** to write **last created filestream** to custom folder

Result is = **empty files (0Ko)** (image attached)

Product : MSSQL server 2012 sp4 express

```
    BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @NameFile VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @StreamID VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SaveDirectory VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @FileData VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @ObjectToken INT

select @StreamID= i.stream_id, @NameFile = i.name from inserted i

set @FileData=(select file_stream from DocumentFiles where stream_id = @StreamID)
set @SaveDirectory = 'C:\Temp\'+ REPLACE(@NameFile, 'V-FA-', '')

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod  @ObjectToken, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod  @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL,@FileData
EXEC sp_OAMethod  @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @SaveDirectory, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod  @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

END
```

[image]

Comment: Your trigger code has a **MAJOR** flaw. It assumes there will only ever be one row in inserted. Triggers in sql server are called once per operation and the inserted and deleted tables can and will have multiple rows in them.

Comment: thanks for your comment, what do you suggest please ?

Comment: @SeanLange i have only selected Stream_Id and name from inserted table, after that i'm trying to get StreamFile using Stream_Id

Comment: For the situation you are in you are going to need to wrap this in a cursor to ensure you capture all rows being inserted.

Comment: actually inserted table contain only one row, which is the last inserted row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_OAMethod returns a value that indicates whether the action was performed without error. You can try to track down the problem by wrapping each call with a similar code:

```
EXEC  @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d ADODB.Stream.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d Type.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d Open.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @BinaryData
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    SET @Error='Error %d Write. '+@SourceName
                    RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FilePath, 2
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d SaveToFile.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d Close.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
EXEC  @hr = sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
        IF @hr <> 0  
            BEGIN  
                    RAISERROR('Error %d Destroy.', 16, 1, @hr)
                    RETURN
            END
```

Comment: i'll edit the query and give you feedback, thank you